# Selecting Multiple Options, Then Submitting

Tags: javascript, web

This is more of a conceptual question than a specific question about code. As a relative novice to using javascript to create webpages, I've run into a dilemma:

- I'm making a website for teachers (am a teacher) that tracks participation for students.
- A pop-up appears -- all of the student's names are listed.
- Any name that is clicked on gets switched to the selected state ... I'm just switching around CSS classes to make the name buttons look "clicked" or not.

What's the best way to get all of the names that need data attributed to them submitted through? Do I make a submit button that reads all of it when clicked, do I add data as soon as a name is clicked, or is it something else? I've tried it a few different ways and keep hitting roadblocks. Thoughts?

Comment: There are any number of ways to implement something like this—without context (and possibly even with) there’s no generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered use a native `select` control with `multiple` attribute as seen below?

You could include this in a form and the browser would handle which values are selected, etc.. for you and include them in the form submission.

You can select multiple items using ctrl+click.

```html
<select name="students" multiple style="width: 150px;">
  <option>Student 1</option>
  <option>Student 2</option>
  <option>Student 3</option>
  <option>Student 4</option>
  <option>Student 5</option>
  <option>Student 6</option>
</select>
```